# Continuously renders a previous rendered version, not what is currently in the scene (Cycles Render)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Whenever I render my scene, it always renders a previous render which I had done for testing purposes a while ago. It's not an animation or anything, just a still shot of a car I modelled with some lights to make it shiny (putting that detail there just encase it's useful).

I've searched around online for an answer, where I found another person with a similar problem to mine, yet his was fixed by deleting a strip in the VSE (video sequence editor) and I don't have any strips in mine, so it was not helpful.

Here is the model: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/37866

(If you get the model, switch the top right viewport to the "viewport render" mode to see how it's suppose to look, and then do a proper (low sample) render just to see what I mean)

Answer (score 3):

In your case the difference between the viewport and final render is caused by some emission objects which are hidden only in the final render.

In the *Outliner* there are eye and camera icons that control the visibility of a given object in the viewport and final render, respectively:

[image]

Objects with the camera icon disabled will not affect the final render.

Comment: Ah! Thank you, that was the problem! Something so simple yet causing much time of frustration... Thanks again for the solution!